# How to load a saved model from TensorFlow word2vec tutorial and use for word comparisons

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec

I am new to TensorFlow, word2vec, and neural networks and I am trying to learn about them.  I am working on this TensorFlow tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec.  I ran the word2vec_optimized.py code for the tutorial which is found here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/embedding/word2vec_optimized.py. When the tutorial code is finished running, it outputs a saved TensorFlow model.  I am trying to see if I can re-load the model and use it to make word comparisons, i.e. France is to Paris as Russia is to Moscow.

I see in the tutorial code there is an analogy method which could be used for this:

```
def analogy(self, w0, w1, w2):
    """Predict word w3 as in w0:w1 vs w2:w3."""
    wid = np.array([[self._word2id.get(w, 0) for w in [w0, w1, w2]]])
    idx = self._predict(wid)
    for c in [self._id2word[i] for i in idx[0, :]]:
      if c not in [w0, w1, w2]:
        print(c)
        break
    print("unknown")
```

But first, I need to re-load the saved model, which I do in my main method:

```
def main(_):
  with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as session:
    with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
      model = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.ckpt.meta')
      model.restore(session, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/results/'))
      model.analogy(b'france', b'paris', b'russia')
```

This results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./word2vec_test.py", line 539, in <module>
  tf.app.run()
  File "/util/opt/anaconda/2.2/envs/tensorflow-1.0.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "./embedding_tutorial/embedding/word2vec_test.py", line 534, in main
    model.analogy(b'france', b'paris', b'russia')
AttributeError: 'Saver' object has no attribute 'analogy'
```

How can I load the saved module and use it to call the analogy method?  I'm putting my main method in the same file as the analogy method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `analogy()` is a method of class `Word2Vec` however you are not instantiating the `model` into that type of object.

Try this:

```
opts = Options()
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as session:
  with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    model = Word2Vec(opts, session)
    model.saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/path/to/model.ckpt.meta')
    model.saver.restore(session, 
                        tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/path/to/results/'))
    model.analogy(b'france', b'paris', b'russia')
```

Or actually if you used [--interactive](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/1464a721fef7da67e87b0f1f1a710b1e904e8764/tutorials/embedding/word2vec_optimized.py#L78) when you train, you will enter into the [interactive mode](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/1464a721fef7da67e87b0f1f1a710b1e904e8764/tutorials/embedding/word2vec_optimized.py#L431) with ipython after the training is done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I tried the code above and it came back with this error:


 `NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key sm_w_t not found in checkpoint
         [[Node: save/RestoreV2_3 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_3/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_3/shape_and_slices)]]`


The full error is quite long, but I can post the rest of the traceback if it would be helpful.  I will also try the --interactive flag for the training, but it will take some time before it will finish training again.

Comment: I updated the code snippet. try again? To see if that --interactive works, you can set --epochs_to_train=1 (instead of the default value of 15) to wait less time.

Comment: I'm having the same error with the new code: 
`   NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key sm_w_t not found in checkpoint
         [[Node: save/RestoreV2_3 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_3/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_3/shape_and_slices)]]`  

Should it matter if there is more than one model in the results folder?  I've generated the model more than once.  Thanks!

Comment: Also trying to run training with 1 epoch

Comment: I was able to use the analogy function through interactive mode.